# Redefine obeyspaces to newline

Tags: spacing, environments

I want to typeset code snippets from different programming languages. I couldn't get `listings` to do what I want (one complete height of an empty line takes up too much space for my liking) and neither did I manage to define everything I want myself.

I'd like to define a new environment where return calls `\newline`, and where an empty line calls `\par` (this one is already present in normal text mode) so that I can differentiate between them. In addition, every space inserted should be printed, but that is taken care of by `\obeyspaces`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newenvironment{code}{
\ttfamily
\parindent=0pt\parskip=5pt
\obeyspaces\obeylines
}{}

\begin{document}
\begin{code}
text 1space  2spaces
new line

empty line before this line
\end{code}
\end{document}
```

I found

```
\def\obeypar{\catcode`\^^M\active \let ^^M\par }`
```

and tried to define `\obeylines` (LaTeX tells me it's undefined) but since these are TeX primitives (?) they give an error. 
Can I tell LaTeX that this part should be treated as TeX?

What am I missing or where I can read about these things?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Doesn't `verbatim` already offer what you're looking for?

Comment: Thank you. Verbatim does, at least from my understanding of the documentation, the same as listings: they only use `\par` and are thus not able to differentiate between par and newline, so I end up with either the normal space between lines (of a paragraph) or with the full space of an empty line, and I'd like to make that last space smaller (horizontally), about 0.5.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how you want this to look. Could you mock up in some way how you'd like the output to look: for example, do you mean that you don't want a blank line in the output even if the code has a blank line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand the question, you need to distinguish the empty and non-empty lines in `code` environment. You can try the following:

```
\def\emptyline{\hbox to\hsize{\dotfill empty line\dotfill}}
%\def\emptyline{\vskip.7\baselineskip} % ... another alternative ...
\def\printemptyline#1{\def\par{\ifvmode\emptyline\fi\endgraf}\obeylines}

\begin{code}\printemptyline
text 1space  2spaces
new line

empty line before this line
\end{code}
```

This gives the result:

[image: empty line]

Comment: Thank you very much, to distinguish empty lines from line breaks is what I was looking for. Next time I'll try to better explain my question.